# How to compare dates in filenames?

Tags: python, date

I got a directory which contains:

```
file_19911210.bak
another_19921212.bak
file_19931212.bak
yes_20010130.bak
more_20120212.bak
```

Based on the date;
I want to create a script in python to output the 2 newest files as:

```
[new] yes_20010130.bak
[new] more_20120212.bak
```

The rest as:

```
[old] file_19911210.bak
[old] another_19921212.bak
[old] another_19931212.bak
```

What modules and `how to` would you advise?

Comment: You do not need any modules. When dates are written in the format YYYYMMDD you can just sort them as they were integers.

Comment: @Elmex80s that would work if the dates were at the start of the filename, however the question says otherwise.

Comment: @PeterWood I know, I left some little work to do for himself ;-) It is not a code-service after all.

Comment: Exactly. It's not like i'm asking for answer, but guidance. Don't know why i'm getting -2 for my question..

Answer (score 1):

You can sort a sequence based upon some `key`. The key we want is the 12th to the 5th characters from the end of the filename to give the timestamp:

```
>>> def timestamp(filename):
...     return filename[-12:-4]

>>> timestamp('file_19911210.bak')
'19911210'

>>> filenames = [
...     'file_19911210.bak',
...     'another_19921212.bak',
...     'file_19931212.bak',
...     'yes_20010130.bak',
...     'more_20120212.bak']

>>> sorted(filenames, key=timestamp)
```